# Error in uploading JSON to IBM Watson Discovery

Tags: json, watson

Whenever I am trying to Upload A `JSON` to `IBM` `Discovery` as it shows an error.
The error message:

> 400 - Top-level array JSON documents are not supported

Is there a specific format my JSON needs to be in before uploading. I basically want to upload a table with columns and rows to Discovery! I have also attached a samle JSON file which I want to upload. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GBaY.png)

any help is much appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQDpF.png)

Comment: As per the error message, it is not expecting the top level element to be an array. Can you put the array as key value and then try? so instead of `[{"your_key":"your_value.....}]` it will then be `{"values": [{"your_key":"your_value.....}] }`

Comment: Hey suvartheec, You were right. Now it's working. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Glad i could help. Please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error message, it is not expecting the top level element to be an array. Can you put the array as key value and then try? so instead of `[{"your_key":"your_value.....}]` it will then be `{"values": [{"your_key":"your_value.....}] }`